# List posts only for certain period in wp query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On WordPress how can I get this done?

Limit wp query to list posts only upto recent one year (365 days) and do not list posts which is older then 365 days.

Is there any plugin for this? Please advise.

Comment: You don't need a plugin, take a look here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example on codex that shows how to list posts from the last 30 days:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

You should adapt it to fit your needs, e.g. (not tested) :

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

$date1yrback = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", mktime()) . " - 365 day")); // Find Date 1 year back

$countp = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$my_date = the_date('Y-m-d', FALSE);    //Find Post Date

if($my_date > $date1yrback)             //Check if Post date is greater than date year back
{
    echo "<h1>".the_title()."</h2>";
    echo "<p>".the_content()."</p>";
    $countp++;                          //Increment counter as post in above criteria is found
}

endwhile; endif; 

if($countp == 0)
{
    ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php 
}

?>
```